# Fast-endpoints global headers in swagger for all endpoints

Tags: .net-core, minimal-apis, fast-endpoints

I am using [fast-endpoints](https://github.com/FastEndpoints/FastEndpoints) library for building a minimal API. I need to have two generic headers (name, tracking-Id) across all methods of all the resources.

To implement this requirement, I have used a custom implementation of `IGlobalPreProcessor` which checks if the incoming requests have these headers. It sends out a validation failure message if the headers are not present.

However on the swagger page, I don't see these two headers. I need help to add these two headers on swagger.

I have tried to implement `IOperationProcessor`, but not sure how to use it with fast-endpoints as
`builder.services.AddOpenApiDocument()` is called inside fast-endpoints extension `builder.Services.SwaggerDocument()`

Comment: FastAPI is a Python framework, isn't it? Why did you add the .NET Core tag?

Comment: @YasinARLI FastEndpoints is an ASP.NET REST API framework. He's not talking about FastAPI.

Comment: @YasinARLI Oh yes! It is FastEndpoints. Havent tagged FastApi. And you must check it out this lib if you are building APIs using dotnet. Team is pretty active on SO and Discord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can register an `IOperationProcessor` like this with FastEndpoints:

```cs
builder.Services.SwaggerDocument(o =>
{
    o.DocumentSettings = s => s.OperationProcessors.Add(new AddCustomHeader());
});
```

and here's an example processor that adds a custom header to the swagger doc globally:

```cs
internal sealed class AddCustomHeader : IOperationProcessor
{
    public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        var hdrParameter = new OpenApiParameter()
        {
            Name = "x-custom",
            Kind = OpenApiParameterKind.Header,
            IsRequired = true,
            Type = JsonObjectType.String,
            Default = "xyz",
            Description = "The description of the field"
        };

        context.OperationDescription.Operation.Parameters.Add(hdrParameter);

        return true;
    }
}
```